# MSSQL : Insert value of execute statement together with another string in a table

Tags: sql-server

**What I have**

I am currently inserting all the SQL files from the current directory in a temporary table :

```
create table #tmpSQLFiles(SQLFileName varchar(max))  
set @SqlStatement = 'master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''dir /b "' + @DirPath + '*.sql"'''

insert into #tmpSQLFiles
execute (@SqlStatement)
```

This works well.

**What I want**

Now I want the table to have an extra `varchar` column in which I can store a certain desired string :

```
create table #tmpSQLFiles(SQLFileName varchar(max), MyString varchar(max))
set @SqlStatement = 'master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''dir /b "' + @DirPath+ '*.sql"'''
```

**What I have tried**

How can I do the insert? I have tried :

```
insert into #tmpSQLFiles (SQLFileName, MyString) values (execute (@SqlStatement), 'aa')
```

or :

```
declare @ExecutedStmt varchar(max)
set @ExecutedStmt = execute (@SqlStatement)
-- But the above line is not correct.
```

Any of these 2 would work for me. I don't want to insert and update afterwards the second column.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this? Thank you !

Comment: What is the error you are getting with the second block you tried? "set @ExecutedStmt = execute (@SqlStatement)"

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the word execute.

Comment: Is `MyString` going to be the same string for every row?

Comment: Yes, but I want to set it at insert time, because there will be multiple similar inserts (so I am trying to avoid inserting all the SQLFileNames and updating all the table afterwards with the 2nd column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a table variable as an intermediary - not the prettiest, but does the job:

```
create table #tmpSQLFiles(SQLFileName varchar(max), MyString varchar(max))
set @SqlStatement = 'master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''dir /b "' + @DirPath + '*.pdf"'''

DECLARE @TempOutpt TABLE ([output] varchar(500))
insert into @TempOutpt ([output])
execute (@SqlStatement)

insert into #tmpSQLFiles (SQLFileName, MyString)
select [output], 'my string here' from @TempOutpt

select * from #tmpSQLFiles
```

If you weren't using an extended stored procedure (`xp_cmdshell`), you might have been able to use `OPENROWSET` to execute the SP:

```
SELECT *fields* 
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 
                'Server=*your_server*;Trusted_Connection=yes;Database=*your_database*', 
                'exec *stored_procedure* *parameters*')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an output parameter so you can use the results in the next INSERT:

```
 DECLARE @result INT, @sql NVARCHAR(512) 

    SET @sql = N'SELECT @result = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @dbname + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES' 

    EXEC sp_executesql 
        @query = @sql, 
        @params = N'@result INT OUTPUT', 
        @result = @result OUTPUT 

    PRINT @result
```

Comment: I am executing a windows command, not a stored procedure. Can I still use this in the same way?

Comment: If the first part of your question works, I'm sure this will too. Since getting the output from the EXEC statement is a 2-stage process, you will be better off executing it in a loop.